# How to remove a certain substring in C#

Tags: c#, string, substring

So I have a few file extensions in my C# projects and I need to remove them from the file name if they are there.

So far I know I can check if a Sub-string is in a File Name.

```
if (stringValue.Contains(anotherStringValue))
{  
    // Do Something // 
}
```

So if say `stringValue` is `test.asm`, and then it contains `.asm`, I want to somehow remove the `.asm` from `stringValue`.

How can I do this?

Comment: what if the string value is `helloworld` and you want to remove `l`. does it means it will removed all matching string and the output will be `heoword`?

Comment: You should use `EndsWith(".asm")` (or use [Path.GetExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension.aspx)) to avoid corner cases like "filename.asmo.doc" (`Contains` will return a false positive here)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you want a "blacklist" approach coupled with the `Path` library:

```
// list of extensions you want removed
String[] badExtensions = new[]{ ".asm" };

// original filename
String filename = "test.asm";

// test if the filename has a bad extension
if (badExtensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(filename).ToLower())){
    // it does, so remove it
    filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename);
}
```

examples processed:

```
test.asm        = test
image.jpg       = image.jpg
foo.asm.cs      = foo.asm.cs    <-- Note: .Contains() & .Replace() would fail
```

Comment: I feel as if this is the cleanest/nicest way to process it, and is easily addable for more extensions. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

You can use [Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filepath)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension(v=vs.100).aspx)  to do it.

```
if (Path.GetExtension(stringValue) == anotherStringValue)
{  
    stringValue = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(stringValue);
}
```

Comment: This will get false positives if `anotherStringValue` exists anywhere in the string, even if it's not the extension.

Comment: Probably also want to use `.ToLower()`, or `String.Compare` with insensitive flag to avoid any CasE issues.

Answer (score 6):

No need for the if(), just use :

```
stringValue = stringValue.Replace(anotherStringValue,"");
```

if `anotherStringValue` is not found within `stringValue`, then no changes will occur.

Comment: I strongly recommend against this; it will remove _all_ occurrences, not just the extension.

Comment: at the very least I would check `EndsWith(anotherStringValue)` and use `stringValue.SubString(0, stringValue.Length - anotherStringValue.Length)`

Answer (score 3):

One more one-liner approach to getting rid of only the ".asm" at the end and not any "asm" in the middle of the string:

```
stringValue = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(stringValue,".asm$","");
```

The "$" matches the end of the string.

To match ".asm" or ".ASM" or any equivlanet, you can further specify Regex.Replace to ignore case:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpresions;
...
stringValue = Regex.Replace(stringValue,".asm$","",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```